# Помогите с запросом-SQL

Tags: php, mysql, sql, запрос, таблицы

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Есть такая бд с таблицами.

Допустим есть 3 секции(sections), в каждой секции разное кол-во уроков(lessons), для каждого аккаунта предусмотрен отчет(reports) по каждому уроку. Состояние checked может менять только определенная группа юзеров.

Суть вопроса:

Имеется какой-то id аккаунта. Надо получить выборку секций, которые он прошел. Скажем если юзер с id = 100 прошел все уроки 1 секции(прошел: reports.checked = 1), и 2 урока из 5-ти во 2 секции, то запрос должен вернуть данные только по 1 секции.

Запрос в студию пожалуйста

Comment: напишите пример с данными

Answer (score 0, accepted):

вроде все просто: внутри находим секции, в которых отсутствуют отмеченные уроки. снаружи находим секции, для которых не существует секции с отсутствующими отмеченными. такое двойное отрицание )

```
select * from sections
where not exists (
    select top 1 * from sections as s
    join lessons as l on (s.Id = l.section_id)
    where s.Id = sections.Id
      and not exists (
        select * from reports as r
        where l.id = r.lesson_id
          and r.checked = 1
    )
)
```

или с явно разделенными логическими частями запроса

```
with notChecked as (
    select s.id from sections as s
    join lessons as l on (s.Id = l.section_id)
    where not exists (
        select * from reports as r
        where l.id = r.lesson_id
            and r.checked = 1
    )
)
select * from sections
where not exists (
    select top 1 * from notChecked
    where sections.id = notChecked.id
)
```